# Count query help for big data with join to jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, bigdata

I have a problem about counting rows in a really huge table, that filtered with by object inside JSONB column and joined once

Here is my current query to count it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT s.mid
    FROM "whatsapp-cloud".statuses s
    LEFT JOIN "whatsapp-cloud".outbounds o ON s.mid = o.mid 
    WHERE s."data"->'entry'->0->'changes'->0->'value'->'statuses'->0->'conversation'->'origin'->>'type' = 'utility'
        AND s."type" = 'delivered'
        AND s.created_at::date = '2023-02-28'::date
        and s.account_id  = {account_id}
        AND o."type" = 'template'
) AS counter;
```

About the big table I said before, it was `"whatsapp-cloud".statuses` with current space size at 77GB and 43492221 estimated total rows according to `analyze` query.
Here is the table structure of `"whatsapp-cloud".statuses`

**Edit -  I change the images of table structure into DDL query for better understanding**

```
CREATE TABLE "whatsapp-cloud".statuses (
id varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1()::character varying(50),
client_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
channel_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
account_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
application_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
"oid" varchar(150) NULL,
xid varchar(100) NULL,
mid varchar(200) NOT NULL,
"type" varchar(50) NULL,
error varchar(50) NULL,
"data" jsonb NOT NULL,
created_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
CONSTRAINT statuses_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE INDEX idx_statuses_account_id ON "whatsapp-cloud".statuses USING btree (account_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_statuses_channel_id ON "whatsapp-cloud".statuses USING btree (channel_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_statuses_cid ON "whatsapp-cloud".statuses USING btree (oid);
CREATE INDEX idx_statuses_client_id ON "whatsapp-cloud".statuses USING btree (client_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_statuses_mid ON "whatsapp-cloud".statuses USING btree (mid);
CREATE INDEX idx_statuses_xid ON "whatsapp-cloud".statuses USING btree (xid);
CREATE INDEX idx_whatsapp_cloud_type ON "whatsapp-cloud".statuses USING btree (type);
CREATE INDEX statuses_date_of_tz_idx ON "whatsapp-cloud".statuses USING btree (date_of_tz(created_at));
```

And here is `"whatsapp-cloud".outbounds` structure

```
CREATE TABLE "whatsapp-cloud".outbounds (
id varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1()::character varying(50),
xid varchar(100) NULL,
mid varchar(200) NULL,
client_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
channel_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
account_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
application_id varchar(50) NULL,
"type" varchar(50) NULL,
recipient varchar(350) NOT NULL,
error varchar(50) NULL,
"data" jsonb NOT NULL,
"result" jsonb NULL,
created_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
updated_at timestamp NULL,
CONSTRAINT outbounds_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE INDEX idx_outbound_created_at ON "whatsapp-cloud".outbounds USING btree (((timezone('UTC'::text, created_at))::date));
CREATE INDEX idx_outbounds_account_id ON "whatsapp-cloud".outbounds USING btree (account_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_outbounds_channel_id ON "whatsapp-cloud".outbounds USING btree (channel_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_outbounds_client_id ON "whatsapp-cloud".outbounds USING btree (client_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_outbounds_mid ON "whatsapp-cloud".outbounds USING btree (mid);
CREATE INDEX idx_outbounds_xid ON "whatsapp-cloud".outbounds USING btree (xid);
CREATE INDEX outbounds_date_of_tz_idx ON "whatsapp-cloud".outbounds USING btree (date_of_tz(created_at));
CREATE INDEX outbounds_month_of_tz_idx ON "whatsapp-cloud".outbounds USING btree (month_of_tz(created_at));
CREATE INDEX outbounds_type_idx ON "whatsapp-cloud".outbounds USING btree (type);
CREATE INDEX outbounds_year_of_tz_idx ON "whatsapp-cloud".outbounds USING btree (year_of_tz(created_at));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidx_outbounds_xid ON "whatsapp-cloud".outbounds USING btree (xid, client_id);
```

The catch is, as you see, my query needs to look deep into certain JSONB column.

Combined with a join is already make this query run so long. Depending on `{account_id}`, if it was like 0 count it should be only took 1 second or faster, but since this `"whatsapp-cloud".outbounds` table has characteristic of logs type table, there are many case that the result might be 10K or even 100K count result.

To make it worse, I made this into script to execute this query as many `{account_id}` which is currently about 100s `account_id` **everyday**. I set CRON job to execute this script and it start from 00:01, and usually finished about more than 13 hours and the worst case almost 17 hours everyday.

Is there any way to make my query better? or any way to make it faster?

**Edit 2**

Here is the result from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` from my query.

*Note: This is the result when Count = 0*

```
|QUERY PLAN|
|----------|
|Aggregate  (cost=23344.51..23344.52 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.089..0.090 rows=1 loops=1)|
|  Output: count(*)|
|  ->  Unique  (cost=23344.49..23344.50 rows=1 width=62) (actual time=0.085..0.086 rows=0 loops=1)|
|        Output: s.mid|
|        ->  Sort  (cost=23344.49..23344.49 rows=1 width=62) (actual time=0.084..0.085 rows=0 loops=1)|
|              Output: s.mid|
|              Sort Key: s.mid|
|              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB|
|              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.13..23344.48 rows=1 width=62) (actual time=0.048..0.049 rows=0 loops=1)|
|                    Output: s.mid|
|                    ->  Index Scan using idx_statuses_account_id on "whatsapp-cloud".statuses s  (cost=0.56..23335.89 rows=1 width=62) (actual time=0.047..0.048 rows=0 loops=1)|
|                          Output: s.id, s.client_id, s.channel_id, s.account_id, s.application_id, s.oid, s.xid, s.mid, s.type, s.error, s.data, s.created_at|
|                          Index Cond: ((s.account_id)::text = '{account_id}'::text)|
|                          Filter: (((s.type)::text = 'delivered'::text) AND ((s.created_at)::date = '2023-02-28'::date) AND (((((((((((s.data -> 'entry'::text) -> 0) -> 'changes'::text) -> 0) -> 'value'::text) -> 'statuses'::text) -> 0) -> 'conversation'::text) -> 'origin'::text) ->> 'type'::text) = 'utility'::text))|
|                    ->  Index Scan using idx_outbounds_mid on "whatsapp-cloud".outbounds o  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=62) (never executed)|
|                          Output: o.id, o.xid, o.mid, o.client_id, o.channel_id, o.account_id, o.application_id, o.type, o.recipient, o.error, o.data, o.result, o.created_at, o.updated_at|
|                          Index Cond: ((o.mid)::text = (s.mid)::text)|
|                          Filter: ((o.type)::text = 'template'::text)|
|Planning Time: 316.699 ms|
|Execution Time: 0.258 ms|
```

Comment: I can't read any of the teeny tiny text on those images. You may want to repost them as text. Also the first thing people will ask for is the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

Comment: Which type of index has this table? If you are using BTREE try with GIN, sometimes has better performance with JSON queries

Comment: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pagination-problem-total-result-count/#total-count

Comment: @RichardHuxton I have changed the images with DDL query of those tables

Comment: That explain says it takes 0.2ms to get your count. It isn't going to get much faster than that, is it? If that explain doesn't show the problem, why have you chosen it?

Comment: @RichardHuxton it takes 0.2ms for 0 count, but in some case, depending on parameters I could get more than 10K counts, and in this case it took a very long time. What worse is I need to loop the query with up to more than 100 {account_ids}. Because of the table "whatsapp".statuses is a table with fast data entries, like almost 1 GB per day, I want to make this query count faster.